# actionscript 2 to actionscript 3 my code

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

can someone help me to transform this code from as2 to as3?

For a simple circle, i want when i go with mouse cursor to right , the circle to rotate (don't need to move my mouse cursor but the circle still rotating)

I know that `_root._xmouse` goes t mouseX and `this._rotation` goes to `this.DisplayObject.rotation`

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame)
{
    this.xmouse = Math.min(908, Math.max(0, _root._xmouse));
    if (_root._xmouse > 0) 
    {
        var offset = Stage.width / 2 - this.xmouse;
        this._rotation = this._rotation + offset / 2000;
    } else {
        this._rotation = this._rotation - 0.02;
    }
    this._rotation = this._rotation % 180;
}
```

AS3 version:

```
stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, mouseOver );

function mouseOver( e: Event ) : void

{
    rota.mouseX == Math.min(908, Math.max(0, stage.mouseX));
    if (stage.mouseX > 0) 
    {
        var offset = stage.stage.width / 2 - rota.mouseX;
        rota.rotation = rota.rotation + offset / 2000;
    }else{
        rota.rotation = rota.rotation - 0.02;
    }
    rota.rotation = rota.rotation % 180;
}
```

Comment: _"Don't need to move my mouse cursor but the circle still rotating"_... thats what an `EnterFrame` does. It repeats the code at FPS rate of your SWF. Maybe you want that code logic inside an `Mouse_Move` listener? Show the AS3 version code that you tried to make, easier to help you fix it.

Comment: yes maybe a mouse_move listener,  how this as2 code may works (as a as3 code)...?

Comment: We need to see the AS3 code you have so far to show how that as2 logic  can be applied. For example : nobody knows your circle variable names etc.. you could replace `this` with whatever your Circle variable name is and use that as `circleName.rotation = circleName.rotation % 180;` etc etc

Comment: i may apply the variable before let's call the circle "test"  just the way this code (as2) can be transformed to as3 to work..

Comment: _"Convert this code for me"_ and _"write my code"_ Questions are not for Stackoverflow. See [**`How to Ask`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. I'm willing to help correct any mistakes in your AS3 effort. Use [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43284929/edit) button to add your AS3 effort for a **faster answer**.  Anyways `_root.` is AS3 `stage.` etc. Also `this` is not necessary so either just use `test` or `event.currentTarget` (_currentTarget_ talks to the Mouse Move listener). Without AS3 code to see it's really hard to advise you.

Comment: ok i added a as3 version.

Comment: I've added an Answer. (PS: If you like it... wait 24 to 48 hrs before marking it correct. It's important to wait. thanks)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
var offset : int = 0; //declare the variable (integer)

//stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoving );
rota.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoving );

function mouseMoving ( evt : Event ) : void
{
    rota.x = stage.mouseX; //Math.min(908, Math.max(0, stage.mouseX));

    if (stage.mouseX > 0) 
    {
        offset = stage.stage.width / 2 - rota.mouseX;
        rota.rotation = rota.rotation + offset / 2000;
    }else{
        rota.rotation = rota.rotation - 0.02;
    }
    rota.rotation = rota.rotation % 180;
}
```

notes / tips :

- Declare variables outside of functions where possible.
- The `evt` in `( evt : Event )` is your target reference to whatever has the `.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE)` attached to it. So if you want to move more than one thing, just give them all the same `addEvent` same like `rota.addEvent...` but as you can see the function moves only `rota` at present, so by changing code to using `evt.rotation` and `evt.mouseX` etc... the `evt` now makes it **universal** to anything listening to that `mouseMoving` function.

---

**Edit** (based on comments) :

The variable `speed` sets speed of rotation. For `rotation` set the direction by either `-=` or `+=`.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoving ); //Stage : for direction
rota.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mouseRotating); //Object : for spin/rotate

var prevX:int = 0;
var currX:int = 0;
var directX: int = 0; //will update to 1=Left or 2=Right

var speed : int = 7; //speed of rotation

function mouseMoving ( evt : Event ) : void
{
    prevX = currX; currX = stage.mouseX; 

    if (prevX > currX) { directX = 1; }  //moving = LEFT
    else if (prevX < currX) { directX = 2; } //moving = RIGHT
    //else { directX = 0;} //moving = NONE

}

function mouseRotating ( evt : Event ) : void
{
    evt.target.x = stage.mouseX; //follow mouse

    if ( directX == 1 ) { evt.currentTarget.rotation -= speed; }
    if ( directX == 2 ) { evt.currentTarget.rotation += speed; }

}
```

Comment: i like this thanks! , and how i do if i want that circle to keep moving to the right if i go to mouse to the right and then i stop moving the mouse but the circle is still rotating to right (same thing to left)

Comment: Thanks but can you **un-accept** the Answer for now?. I'm trying to get my rep score to `6-6-6-6` for a joke to friend and the `✓` has pushed it too far. You can always re-like after weekend or such.

Comment: I need to get on Flash first. Maybe within 1 hour. Also I think you need a different logic than the other AS2 & AS3 code. You need degrees not `.rotation % 180;` etc...

Comment: hmm.. i'll wait ! :) Thanks

Comment: @romania check if the new **edit** does what you want? PS: That _"within 1 hour"_ should be _"within 1 day"_. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is what i wanted ! thanks, but how i can fix the circle(to stay in front)?  (just the rotate thing is what i wanted)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by _"stay in front"_. In the function **MouseRotating** those `evt.target.` and `evt.currentTarget.` are linked to `rota` object (meaning it is the Event's _target_). So adjust or remove or add anything there to affect the target (rota).